# mysql - Return all items in one row

Tags: mysql

Is there a function in mysql that would return all items in just one row?

**EXAMPLE:**

```
Table:

| id | name |
-------------
| 1  | john |
| 2  | mike |
| 3  | jane |
```

**Query:**

```
SELECT concat_name(name) FROM tbl_name
```

`concat_name` as the function.

**Expected Result:**

```
|       name      |
-------------------
| john, mike, jane|
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `group_concat()`:

```
select group_concat(name order by id separator ',') as name
from table;
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `GROUP_CONCAT` FUNCTION

http://dev.mysql.com/tech-resources/articles/4.1/grab-bag.html

```
SELEct m.meal_Id, 
        GROUP_CONCAT(dish_id) dish_ids, 
        GROUP_CONCAT(dish_name) dish_names
 FROM DISH_HAS_DISHES m JOIN DISH d ON (m.dish_id = d.dish_id)
 GROUP BY meal_Id
```

Comment: Thanks @Harshil for formatting ans. I had given ans from mobile phone so I was not able to format.

Comment: No worries. BTW the link mentioned in your answer is not redirecting to documentation.